# What is the correct way to build signed release APK in react-native?

Tags: react-native, gradle

I'm not so sure if what I'm doing is the **correct way** or **miss some step** or **too much step** that I made. The way to build the APK I retrieve from various finding on tutorial, forum and example. Again, I still not sure the way I'm building it.

I have the generated keystore file on `./android/app` directory
Below are what I found and try but I don't know how it different from each other:

**STEP 1:**

```bsh
> cd android
> gradlew clean
> gradlew assembleRelease
```

**STEP 2:**

```bsh
> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
> cd android
> gradlew assembleRelease
```

**STEP 3:**

```bsh
> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
#Go to ".\android\app\src\main\res" and delete all *drawable-xxxx* and *raw* folder if exist
> cd android
> gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
```

**STEP 4:**

```bsh
> npx jetify
> cd android
> gradlew clean
> gradlew assembleRelease
```

**STEP 5:**

```bsh
# Go to ./android/app/src/main/assets/ and remove `index.android.bundle` file
> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
> cd .\android\app\src\main\res && if exist "drawable-hdpi" rmdir "drawable-hdpi" /q /s && if exist "drawable-mdpi" rmdir "drawable-mdpi" /q /s && if exist "drawable-xhdpi" rmdir "drawable-xhdpi" /q /s && if exist "drawable-xxhdpi" rmdir "drawable-xxhdpi" /q /s && if exist "drawable-xxxhdpi" rmdir "drawable-xxxhdpi" /q /s && if exist "raw" rmdir "raw" /q /s
> cd..\..\..\..\..\android
> gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
```

On the other hand, I also create my own batch file to make this build as APK. This file will be one folder up before project root folder to run.

**build-react-native-release.bat:**

```bsh
@echo off
:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------
if not defined in_subprocess (cmd /k set in_subprocess=y ^& %0 %*) & exit )
set driveName="%CD:~0,2%"
set currentFolder="%~dp0"
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /A count=1
set list=
CD %driveName%

echo ===========================================
for /d %%D in (*) do (
    set "listName=%%~f"
    set list=%listName%%1
    rem echo !listName! !
    echo !count!^. %%~D
    set /a count+=1
)
echo ===========================================
:startAgain
set choice=
set /p choice=Type in target folder from listing to build release APK (e.g. targetfolder): 
if not '%choice%'=='' (
    if exist %choice% (
        set choice=%choice%
        CD %choice%
        goto performbuild
    )
)
echo Invalid directory name!
goto startAgain

:performbuild
echo Script will start build target APK to release on %choice%...
timeout /t 2 /nobreak>nul
cd %currentFolder%%choice%^\android\app\src\main\assets
del "index.android.bundle" 2>nul
cd %currentFolder%%choice%
call react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
rem start "" %currentFolder%%choice%^\android\app\src\main\res
timeout /t 2 /nobreak>nul
cd %currentFolder%%choice%^\android\app\src\main\res
echo Validating duplicating resources
if exist "drawable-hdpi" rmdir "drawable-hdpi" /q /s 2>nul
if exist "drawable-mdpi" rmdir "drawable-mdpi" /q /s 2>nul
if exist "drawable-xhdpi" rmdir "drawable-xhdpi" /q /s 2>nul
if exist "drawable-xxhdpi" rmdir "drawable-xxhdpi" /q /s 2>nul
if exist "drawable-xxxhdpi" rmdir "drawable-xxxhdpi" /q /s 2>nul
if exist "raw" rmdir "raw" /q /s 2>nul
cd %currentFolder%%choice%^\android
call gradlew assembleRelease
cd %currentFolder%%choice%
:choiceOpt
set /P answ=Build complete. Do you want to rebuild again[Y/N]?
if /I "%answ%" EQU "Y" goto :performbuild
if /I "%answ%" EQU "N" goto :justexit
goto :choiceOpt

:justexit
echo Exiting
timeout /t 2 /nobreak>nul
exit
```

And this APK that created on `.\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release` is the one we will be passing to upload to Playstore for verification?

Comment: option 4 (jetify, clean, assemble) is all you need. It will handle bungling js, assets and other things internally. I'm curious as to why you would want to create the js bundle, manipulate assets yourself?

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android this is the official doc for generating release builds

Comment: LonelyCpp, so Budle Release (.aar) is the one we will be uploading to Playstore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So see at last you want a signed APK/bundle to be uploaded to your playstore . To do this as you mentioned the steps all perform the same thing at last. creating a signed APK:

Below steps would be ideal for you to follow :

1.creating a updated js bundle , because that what contains your latest code. This is done for updating your bundle for your react native code. Do check out if your bundle file is named `index.android.bundle` or just `index.bundle` in the `android/app/src/main/assets` directory.

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
```

2.After Android X , you want to migrate all dependenies compatible with android x.
In your react native directory do the below :

`yarn add jetifier` or `npm i jetifier` 
then

```
npx jetify
```

3.After this is done , navigate to android directory  by `cd android` and perform clean operation  this will clean any exiting builds:

```
./gradlew clean
```

1. After that being inside the android directory, you can either create an APK or a bundle. You can upload both to playstore. But i would suggest bundle as it reduces the size of your app significantly.

   a. To build APK : `./gradlew assembleRelease` and this will create an APK in the `/android/app/build/outputs/apk/`
   b.To build bundle :'`./gradlew bundleRelease` and this will create a bundle in `android/app/build/outputs/bundle/`

You can share the APK or upload it, but you cant share bundle, you ccan only upload the bundle to playstore.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Is it recommended to remove the index.android.bundle before bundling the app? I have seen somewhere that there might be a cache that made the bundle having the last build.

Comment: no, nothing like that, yes thats a cache if you dont make a build again.So better always before making an apk try the first step , and if you think the answer helped you, please mark it as accepted. :) would surely help

Comment: your answer do help in describing what is the recommended way with explanation.